# Meaning of Return value 1 in C

Tags: c

This C program return value is 1. What is the meaning of return-value 1 and why it returns 1?

```
void main(){
;;
;;"Hi";;
;;
}
```

And when I use `int main()` then I am getting compile time error- `[Error] ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: Read about [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: `void main` is not legal C++ (or C I think)

Comment: This program is not valid C. `main` is supposed to be declared to return `int`, not `void`

Comment: Assuming your compiler doesn't choke on `void main()`, *any* part of the code can call `exit(1)`. Posting only `main()` will not help much.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Dev-C++ and GCC

Comment: Thie question shows why StackOverflow is problematic. The question currently has a -7 downvote tally. But only 5 people commented on it altogether. So why can the question be downvoted? Yes, the content is incorrect - but the question is still a perfectly valid one. In fact - I found this via a google search, and the people who downvoted the question WERE NOT HELPFUL AT ALL. This is a deficiency of SO as-is. I also suffered from the same - it wastes the time of the one asking the question, and those finding this question.

Answer (score 3):

> This C program return value is 1. What is the meaning of return-value 1 and why it returns 1?

In this case it means anything (undefined behavior).

> And when I use int main() then I am getting compile time error- [Error] ld returned 1 exit status

It means that *abnormal program termination*.

The return value of `main` is a status code that-- in some operating systems-- can be tested when the program terminates. `main` should return `0` if the program terminates normally; to indicate abnormal termination, `main` should return a value other than `0`. (**Actually there is no rule to prevent us from using the return value for other purposes**).

Comment: Actually, it might not mean anything.

Comment: That's not really what I meant. The thing is that the C standard doesn't specify anything about the return value of this program. E.g. GCC just lets the program return some unspecified value to the OS, so it does not have any meaning whatsoever.

Comment: @larsmans; I added a line in the end of my answer-- *Actually there is no rule to prevent us from using the return value for other purposes*

Comment: You seem to misunderstand my point. While the return can be used by a C program for other purposes, *this program cannot* because its return value is indeterminate. It cannot legitimately be used for any purpose.

Comment: Your answer was best so far. Still, the main question of return values in C has not fully been answered so far. I actually found this question because I wanted to find out whether 0 and 1 can be used as false/true in C. Google sent me that way and I am surprised that the answers were not that great, focusing mostly on downvoting (!) the question, which I feel is a misuse of SO (I don't refer to your answere here, but those who downvoted the question).

Comment: @shevy In C, `0` is used to return `true` while any no zero value can be used to return `false` from a function. In case of `main`, values are already defined by the standard for normal and abnormal program termination. Think it like [HTTP response status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) which are already defined -`100–199: Informational responses`, `200–299: Successful responses`, `300–399: Redirects` etc.

Answer (score 2):

First of all there is nothing like `void main()` in `C`. `main()` should always return integer. So returned value may be anything in your case. `void main()` is Undefined in c Standard. Have a look [Here](http://c-faq.com/ansi/maindecl.html).

**According to ISO/IEC 9899
5.1.2.2.1**

`The function called at program startup is named main. The implementation declares no
prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of int ..`

Comment: Did you read the question? The question asked about the return value of 1 - it did NOT ask about main(). Yes, he used main() incorrectly and the method body was wrong too - but that was not the question asked. For some reason people seem to focus first on the incorrect body of the question, rather than the question itself.